# Angular File upload along with JSON as DTO in Spring REST

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I have a requirement like I have to send multiple records as DTO's to REST end point which each record includes a file also along with other data(as JSON/Form Data). What is the best way to implement this using Angular 6 and Spring REST considering other factors like data storage and performance etc..

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: If performance and data storage are important factors, you should probably look at an extended solution utilising (for example) AWS S3 as an intermediate storage. You can leverage AWS Cognito for federated authentication and use existing javascript AWS S3 SDK which handles upload of large files nicely. Spring REST application is then "only" responsible for Cognito integration and picking up files from S3, rather than the upload itself.

Comment: I think, no problem use this approach, see https://grokonez.com/java-integration/angular-6-upload-get-multipartfile-spring-boot-example